# Javascript - How to make ping result always sequential in accordance origin of array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, variables

I want to get result of ping always sequential in accordance origin of array variable.

The code originally from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping)

Here is the code:

```
var ping = require ('net-ping');

var targets = ['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4'];

var session = ping.createSession();

for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    session.pingHost (targets[i], function (error, target, sent, rcvd) {
        var ms = rcvd - sent;
        if (error) {
            if (error instanceof ping.RequestTimedOutError) {
                target;
            } else {
                error.toString ();
            }                      
        } else {
            var result = target + ": " + ms + " ms";
            console.log(result);
        }             
    });
}
```

If i run the code three times, the result is:

```
// first
8.8.8.8: 6 ms
8.8.4.4: 8 ms

// second
8.8.4.4: 7 ms   <- // the list of ip address is not sequential
8.8.8.8: 10 ms  <- // not like the first and third result

// third
8.8.8.8: 5 ms
8.8.4.4: 9 ms
```

I thing the ping result is smallest value in ms (milliseconds) will display first, but how make the result always display consecutive like the origin of array variable `var targets = ['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4']`?

Maybe i must put the result into array and make it sequential, but i don't know how to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: store the results in an array using the index of the target ... output once all targets have `pong`ed or after a suitable timeout (but I see you kind of suggested that already, you just have no idea how to do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises make this quite simple

```
Promise.all(targets.map(tgt => 
    new Promise(resolve => 
        session.pingHost(tgt, (error, target, sent, rcvd) =>
            resolve({error, target, sent, rcvd})
            // resolves to an object containing all the arguments in the callback
            // note: always resolve, even for error - so promise.all can work for you
        )
    )
)).then(results => {
    // results array, same order as targets array
    // process all the results here
    results.forEach(({error, target, sent, rcvd}) => {
        // here are all the original arguments in the callback for pingHost resolved above
        // all the "logic" you perform in the pingHost callback in your code can be done here, and this is after all results are in
    }
});
```

If you want, I can post code that doesn't use promises, but since you're using nodejs, use Promises :p

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
const ping = require ('net-ping');
const targets = ['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4'];
const session = ping.createSession();

async function pingHost (target) {
    return new Promise(resolve => session.pingHost(target, (error, target, sent, rcvd) => {
        var ms = rcvd - sent;
        if (error) {
            if (error instanceof ping.RequestTimedOutError) {
                resolve(target);
            } else {
                resolve(error.toString());
            }                      
        } else {
            var result = target + ": " + ms + " ms";
            resolve(result);
        }             
    }))

}

(async () => {
    for (let target of targets) {
        console.log(await pingHost(target));
    }
})();
```

Comment: that would ping each one in turn, rather than ping them all "at once" and wait for all responses :p

Comment: yes, if you need it otherwise, you need to collect the result and sort them, then print it

Comment: usually pings for practical purposes should be done sequentially, you wont get the real result, if you ping say 1000 hosts in parallel IMO

Comment: I get that - but if you look at the original code, OP sending out multiple pings at *once* - then measuring the delays - I'm not criticising your answer, just pointed out the difference

Comment: @JibyJose, Thank you for your answer, i try to run your code but end with 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'.

Comment: @Ras i updated the code, give it a try, its still hand coded without testing, if there is syntax issues you will have to find it.

Comment: @Jaromanda X i get it, i explicitly added the change, because i think doing like this is better, even though OP did it differently